# What OOP Design Pattern can I use to allow for different types of Address Classes?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a base `Address` class which defines basic address properties and acts as an CRUD object:

- Name
- Company
- Address Line 1
- Address Line 2
- Address Line 3
- City
- State
- Postal Code
- Country

I have a 'ShipToAddress' class which extends Address and includes two more properties:

- Phone Number
- Email Address

`Address` includes validation methods for each of its properties, and `ShipToAddress` includes validation for only its properties (Phone Number and Email Address).

My issue is, I also want to account for both USA and International addresses for both of these classes without duplicating code, so that I can have different validation methods for State and Postal Code. USA State validation would ensure that the value is one of the 50 States. International validation would simply ensure that it does not exceed the length allowed in the database.

How can I design this to allow for any number of different types of addresses (USA, Canada, etc.) but also have the base `Address` class and the `ShipToAddress` class, without duplicating the code? I basically want the following:

- `Address` Base Class
- `ShipToAddress`
- `USAAddress`
- `USAShipToAddress`
- `***Address`
- `***ShipToAddress`

Answer (score 5):

Define AddressValidator as a separate interface.

```
public interface AddressValidator {
    boolean validateAddress(ShipToAddress add);
}
```

Create different implementations of it - `USAAddressValidator`, `CanadaAddressValidator` etc.

You can have a `Factory` to give you the appropriate `AddressValidator` object based on the country.

```
public class AddressValidatorFactory {
    public static AddressValidator GetValidator(Address address) { ... }   
}
```

You should also consider whether `ShipToAddress` should `extend` `Address` or `contain` it. Are you going to pass `ShipToAddress` object where `Address` is expected? If not, then there is no need for `ShipToAddress` to extend Address.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably make it a template, with the validator passed as a template parameter:

```
class US_validator { /* ... */ };

class Int_validator { /* .. */ };

template <class Validator>
class Address { 
   // ...
};

template <class Validator>
class Shipping_address  : public Address {
    // ...
};

typedef Address<US_validator> US_Address;
typedef Address<Int_validator> Int_Address;
typedef Shipping_address<US_validator> US_Shipping_address;
typedef Shipping_address<Int_validator> Int_Shipping_address;
```

Another possibility would be to use multiple inheritance, with the validator as a base class.

```
class US_validator { /* ... */ };
class Int_validator { /* ... */ };

class Address { /* ... */ };
class Shipping_Address : public Address { /* ... */ };

class US_Shipping_Address : public US_validator, public Shipping_Address { /* ... */ };
class Int_Shipping_Address : public Int_validator, public Shipping_Address { /* ... */ };
```

The latter isn't used nearly as often nor (probably) viewed as favorably by most, but can still work perfectly well.

Comment: Yeah, I can't do multiple inheritance in my current environment (ColdFusion 8)

Comment: @Jerry, cant completely disagree with you. A generic Address class, with abstract methods like isPostalCodeValid, getCountryCode (which you can use in your sql statement to get list of states), basically a get for every part of the sql calls you are going to make for all kinds of addresses. This way all AddressTypes extending from Address will be forced to implement those abstract methods. I take back my comment, it is a good question.